# Conditional hover state in LESS

Tags: if-statement, less, conditional-statements, mixins, dotless

I would like to add a conditional hover state to my LESS mixin.

I've tried the following but it returns an error:

```
.foo(@hoverstate:false){

   color:red;

   &:hover when (@hoverstate = true){
      color:blue;
   }

}
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1):

`dotless` does not support ["CSS guard"](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature) construction so you'll need a mixin to put the guard there, e.g.:

```
.foo(@hoverstate: false) {

    color: red;

    .-(); .-() when (@hoverstate = true) {
        &:hover {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

that can be simplified to:

```
.foo(...) {
    color: red;
}

.foo(true) {
    &:hover {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

(Note I did not test this code with `dotless` so it's possible you would need to correct other minor incompatibilities)